# bitwise AND with std::atomic<bool>

Tags: c++11, boolean, atomic

I have an error status boolean that is read/written by multiple threads. It is initially set to true, then should be set to false if any operation fails.

I wanted to use a bitwise AND like so:

```
std::atomic<bool> status;

status &= func1();
status &= func2();
```

but `operator&=` is not allowed between `std::atomic<bool>` and `bool`.

I have been able to use `std::atomic<int>` as work-around to get the same result, but I'm worried that I could have introduced a bug.

Is there a way to get operator& working, or the only viable syntax to use check the return value of func1()/func2() and overwrite status to false please?

Comment: Your plan fails to account for the possibility of `status` changing during the call to `func1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, true and false convert implicitly to 1 and 0 respectively. Therefore, using bit manipulation operations on `bool` is fine (if slightly unusual).
Bitwise manipulation assignment is not supported on `std::atomic<bool>`, but for 'bitwise AND and assign' you could define something like:

```
bool operator&=(atomic<bool> &ab, bool val)
{
    bool tmp = ab.load();

    if (val == false)
        ab.store(false);

    return tmp;
}
```

As M.M pointed out, your fallback scenario to simply assign the return value of `func()` is not thread safe.
Another thread could set it to `false` while you set it to `true` again after `func()` returns.

Comment: Thank you, that's a perfect solution. Very appreciated.

Comment: Your `operator&=` seems to behave differently from what I would expect `operator&=` to do when invoked multiple times in a parallel. Imagine the current `value` holds a `true`, and you call `value &= false` twice in parallel. Depending on the timing, both function calls return `true`, although I would expect only the first call to return `true`, followed by `false` for the second one.